# Архивация большого объёма разбросанных по диску каталогов

Tags: debian, архивация

Планирую переезд на другую машину, в текущей около 300 Гб данных, причем все везде разбросано.

Хотелось бы создать полный дамп всех каталогов, ну и скачать его себе на новую машину, а там вытаскивать оттуда, если что-то понадобится  (т.е не все сразу).

Какими средствами можно это дело провернуть?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [Clonezilla](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla) и виртуалки на новой машине с копией старой.

Comment: Мусорить не охото, перезжаю с сата на SSD, память ограничена...

Comment: @avengerweb, если в интересующих Вас данных нет абсолютных (от корня) символьных ссылок, то можно просто tar-ом (сохраняете владельца, дату и т.д.) эти оглавления на внешний USB-диск перекинуть (все равно введь Ваши 300Gb на новый SSD не влезут), а на  новой монтировать его.

Comment: 300 гигов могут влезть на ssd. они есть уже давно и по 480Гиг.

А так, по существу - можно с помощью dd сделать слепок диска и использовать себе. Но лучше конечно tar  с хорошо настроенным фильтром - там и данных меньше будет:)

А ещё лучше - привести данные в порядок.

Comment: А ещё лучше - привести данные в порядок. C тремя хардами по 2тб было как то не до этого :) а теперь всего 3 по 120

Comment: По поводу таров, сижу, тарюсь...

Comment: Надеюсь рутом и прямо с диска на на диск?

Comment: Рутом, сижу в ожидание чуда.

Comment: я делал через dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=20M | gzip > /mnt/sdb/sda1.img.gz 
скорость копирования вообще не падает, но вот текст и пустые блоки жмутся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предположим, вам надо сделать архив содержимого каталогов:

```
/var/www
/var/vcs
/home/user
```

можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo tar -cf /путь/к/архиву.tar -C / var/www var/vcs home/user
```

сжатие при этом, по-моему использовать не стоит — быстрее будет работать распаковка.

когда потребуется из созданного архива извлечь, например, `home/user` в каталог `/распаковка/home/user`, можно будет это сделать примерно так:

```
$ sudo tar -xf /путь/к/архиву.tar -C /распаковка home/user
```

будут правильно восстановлены и права и принадлежность файлов/каталогов (только учтите, что принадлежность сохраняется не в виде строк, а в виде чисел — номера пользователя и номера группы).